# Using a nested for loop to create a pattern?

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

Need to write a javascript code to prompt a user to input a number. Then create the pattern shown below, using a nested for loop. The number of rows and columns should be equal to the number entered by the user. Any help is appreciated.

Pattern:

```js
....1
...2.
..3..
.4...
5....
```

Okay here is what I have so far. I'm not sure how to embed the numbers into the rows.

```js
let r, s;
let Print = "";
const row = +prompt("Enter number of rows");

for (r = 1; r <= row; r++)
{
 for (s = 1; s <= row; s++)
  Print += "*";
   Print += "\n";
}console.log(Print)
```

Comment: Share your attempt. Seems to be a homework.

Comment: Hi, this seems to be an assignment. Can you please share your effort?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Edited. Wasn't aware of the policy regarding sharing your own attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Use `(s === row - r)` to decide which column you need to write the number to.

```
let r, s;
let Print = "";
const row = 5;

for (r = 0; r < row; r++)
{
    for (s = 1; s <= row; s++)
        Print += (s === row - r) ? s : "*";
      Print += "\n";
}

console.log(Print)
```

The statement `(s === row - r) ? s : "*";` is a short form of `if` statement and the equivalent can be

```
if (s === row - r) {
   Print += s;
} else {
   Print += "*";
}
```